# Mapping function with multiple parameters

Tags: map

So I am trying to print out a table using the map function. My code looks like this:

```
parameters = Table[{a, z}, {a, 1.251,2.5,5.251}, {z, {1, 10, 15, 25, 30}}];

Map[r+a+z &, parameters, {2}]
```

Unfortunately, this gets me a list with the parameters unchanged. What I want is for this function to return a list of the sort `{r+1.251+1},{r+1.251+10},{r+1.251+15}...{r+2.5+1},{r+2.5+10},{r+2.5+15}...` etc etc

Obviously in the final output, the numbers would actually be added up.

Comment: `Map[({r + #[[1]] + #[[2]]}) &, Flatten[parameters, 1]]`

Comment: or `Map[Plus[r, Total@#] &, parameters, {2}]`

Comment: @RMMA! Cool that works. What do the hashtags actually do here?

Comment: `Map[r + Total[#] &, First@parameters]`
The hash mark stands for the argument; the ampersand is postfix for `Function`.  See the documentation for `Function`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should VTC as a simple mistake. Note that `a` and `z` are not stored or remembered in any way as references to anything in `parameters`. Another neat way to solve your problem would be `Total[parameters, {3}] + r`. Further reading is already covered in other comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Join @@ Map[{r + Total@#} &, parameters, {2}]
Join @@ Map[{r + Plus @@ #} &, parameters, {2}]
Join @@ Map[{Total[{r, #}, 2]} &, parameters, {2}]
```

all give

> {{2.251 + r}, {11.251 + r}, {16.251 + r}, {26.251 + r}, {31.251 +  r}, 
>        {3.5 + r}, {12.5 + r}, {17.5 + r}, {27.5 + r}, {32.5 +  r}, {6.251 + r}, 
>        {15.251 + r}, {20.251 + r}, {30.251 + r}, {35.251 + r}}